# Is there a way to have a working drop-down list in a table from a slide in a PowerPoint file that is being displayed in MS Teams?

Tags: excel, powerpoint, microsoft-teams

We have a group that updates Powerpoint slides via MS Teams at different times of the day. We are trying to find a way to not have to download the file every time to make changes to the tables on the slides. The tables have drop-down lists in them. MS Teams shows and recognizes that it's a Powerpoint file but the drop-down doesn't work in the table while previewing it in Teams, even though it sees it as a Powerpoint file.

We tried using the drop down tool for powerpoint but that only works when using Powerpoint. When we use the same file in MS Teams, it sees the file as a Powerpoint file, and only shows a static version of the table drop-down. You can add text to the tables but the drop-down handle is static. Almost as if it is a text-editable snapshot.

We also tried looking for something that works like data validation does in Excel. That could create a drop-down list but the features in the Powerpoint version that is baked into MS Teams doesn't look like it has that feature.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.